# The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,ItemTemplate>.ContainsKey(int)' has some invalid arguments

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm getting these errors too:
Argument `#1' cannot convert`string' expression to type `int'
The best overloaded method match for`System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary.this[int]' has some invalid arguments
Argument `#1' cannot convert`string' expression to type `int'

There's a simplet from my code:

```css
public partial class Chat
{
    void OnSubmit_GMAddon(string text)
    {
        var player = Utils.ClientLocalPlayer();
        if (!player)
            return;
        if (!player.admin)
            return;
        if (!Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text))
        {
            if (text.StartsWith("/give_item"))
            {
                // example usage: /give_item playername count itemname
                ///give_item Ahmet 2 Dark Sword
                List<string> parsed = ParseGMCommand("/give_item", text, 3);

                string user = parsed[0];
                int count = int.Parse(parsed[1]);
                string item = parsed[2];

                if (!Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) && !Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parsed[1]) && !Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                {
                    if (ItemTemplate.dict.ContainsKey(item))
                    {
                        CmdAddToInventory(user, count, item);
                    }
                    else print("invalid item name");
                }
                else print("Invalid Format: Please use /give_item" + user + "/" + count + "/" + item);
            }
```

There's my dictionary simplet:

```css
 static Dictionary<int, ItemTemplate> cache;
    public static Dictionary<int, ItemTemplate> dict {
        get {
            // load if not loaded yet
            return cache ?? (cache = Resources.LoadAll<ItemTemplate>("").ToDictionary(
                item => item.name.GetStableHashCode(), item => item)
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: which part of the code gives you this error?

Comment: Please reduce your code example to the minimum showcasing your problem.

Comment: This error : The best overloaded method match for `System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary<int,ItemTemplate>.ContainsKey(int)' has some invalid arguments //////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

Comment: if (!Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(user) && !Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(parsed[1]) && !Utils.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(item))
                {
                    if (ItemTemplate.dict.ContainsKey(item))
                    {
                        CmdAddToInventory(user, count, item);
                    }
                    else print("invalid item name");
                }

Comment: Wanna contact me by gmail? gabbeaudin02@gmail.com ill let you see my code on unity and visual studio

Comment: you are passing a string instead of an int to your dictionary. either change your dictionary or use `TryParse`.

Comment: Where do i need to change this tryparse? or i don't really know the fonction about the dictionary,..

Comment: Someone can help me over Teamviewer? pls

Answer (score 2):

Your `Dictionary` is declared like this:

```
public static Dictionary<int, ItemTemplate> dict;
```

The key is an `int`, the value is `ItemTemplate`.

---

Later on in your code, your'e checking if it contains a key(remember that your key is an `int` not `string`):

```
string item = parsed[2];
if (ItemTemplate.dict.ContainsKey(item))
```

This is the problem. The `ContainsKey` function expects an `int` since the key is declared as an `int` but you are passing `item` which is `string` and not `int` to it.

---

You have *two* options to fix this:

**1**.Make the key to be a `string` instead of `int`:

```
public static Dictionary<string, ItemTemplate> dict;
```

**2**.Convert the item string to int before passing it to the ContainsKey function:

```
string item = parsed[2];
int itemToInt = 0;

//Convert item to int
if (Int32.TryParse(item, out itemToInt))
{
    //Success. Now check the key
    if (ItemTemplate.dict.ContainsKey(itemToInt))
}
```